# how to implement and use NITZ?

Tags: android, time

After searching internet and asking in here. I found out that the solution to get exact time from simcard is using a service called NITZ(Network Identity and Time Zone) which by the way android uses to set time when user specifies "automatic time syncing" in settings. 
I'm curious to know how I can implement such a thing and use it in my app to get accurate time. 
It appears android use a method called 'revertToNitz()' to sync time. 
I want to use it too. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious to know how I can implement such a thing and use it in my app to get accurate time.

This is handled automatically by the OS. Just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or any other standard Java way to get the time. Apps do not have access to NITZ signals from the carriers.

> It appears android use a method called 'revertToNitz()' to sync time.

There is no `revertToNitz()` in the Android SDK, nor do I even see one in the source code.

Comment: "There is no revertToNitz() in the Android SDK" ORLY? Check here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmServiceStateTracker.java revertToNitzTime()

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: "ORLY?" -- yes, really. "Check here" -- that is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare But if you "use System.currentTimeMillis() or any other standard Java way to get the time", you are relying on the user having set the "Use network time" option, which is not always the case.

Comment: @alfoks: Sure. However, NITZ signals are still not available in the Android SDK to SDK apps. If you want the current time independent of the user's settings, hook up to an SNTP server, or perhaps use the time signal from GPS fixes. NITZ isn't a viable option AFAIK for SDK apps, and not all carriers support NITZ anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I understand that it's not available. I just wanted to point out that currentTimeMillis() is not always an option.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is implemented by the Android OS. If 'Automatic Time' option is switched on by user, you will get the accurate NITZ or NTP time just using the standard system time related API. You need not to concern about it more.
2. And revertToNitzTime() function in implemented in ServiceStateTracker.java. When the phone recieved an NITZ, no matter whether user switches on 'Automatic Time' option, Android will cache this reported time in NITZ. When this option switched on later, its cached value will be applyed to system clock. This operation is called 'revertToNitzTime'.
3. The system time is not only affected by NITZ, but also NTP time. Even GPS time is included in some 3rd party Android system.

Answer (score 0):

Setting time by cellular network in Android (NITZ) is implemented by OS. Check here http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkTimeUpdateService.java